# use sharedpreferenced in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I develop a app that have one activity and a broadcast receiver . i want to set braodcast receiver  in a way that can use some setting that set in activity .

I use code below and its work between two activity but between activity and braodcast receiver cant catch settings .

here my code for saving in avtivity :

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

and this code in braodcast receiver :

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();




        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Password = sp.getString("PASSWORD", "1234");

         int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                         "password is"+Password, duration);
            toast.show();
  }
```

Comment: have you try to initialize `sp` with `PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` inside onReceive ?

Comment: yes i initialize that...

Answer (score 1):

Your receiver is using a file named "myPrefs" but you are using the default filename when setting the preference in your activity.

Use either this one that opens a specific preference file named "myPrefs"

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Or this that opens the default file

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

But not a mixture of the two as they refer to different preferences files.

Comment: can you tell me how to edit "private void savePreferences(String key, String value) " method ?

Comment: Added to answer above.

Comment: ok when i use "SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);" in broadcast receiver its  give some error !

Comment: Also if you have an error, it is helpful to say what the error is.